# How to get nav bar to float to the left of container div without absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I am trying to get my nav bar to sit to the left of the container div (and header img) without having to position it by pixels (as seen here in the codepen: http://cdpn.io/Bfkzx).
I'd like the design to flow responsively, so I'd like to center the main divs (container/ header img) and just have the nav hang out on the left, but I'm having no luck making this happen.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean "flow responsively"? How should the layout change if the browser is resized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to keep your HTML structure the same? You can do this like the following:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

<div id="body">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x150" />

    <div id="container">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/600x800" />
    </div>

</div>
</div><!--//end wrap-->
```

With CSS as follows (I've removed your list styles just for brevity's sake):

```
.wrap { 
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto auto;
}

#nav { 
  width: 160px;
  float: left;
}

#body {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
}
```

You can adjust the top margin of the #nav to bump it down.

Answer (score 0):

I developed an example. I used a display-table approach. Here is a fiddle

[fiddle][1] http://jsfiddle.net/aleruar/3dq5S

```
display:table
```